# List<Struct> .Contains

Tags: c#, list

So recently I'm doing a task where I have to use enums and structs, also lists.
I'm at the point where I have to check for some values. I have tried using .Contains in many ways though I haven't found a good solution.
Is there any possible way to use .Contains on a struct or do I have to redo something?

Part 1 of the code:

```
public static List<FoodItem> FoodL()
{
    List<FoodItem> FoodL = new List<FoodItem>();
    FoodItem food1 = new FoodItem();
    FoodItem food2 = new FoodItem();
    FoodItem food3 = new FoodItem();

    food1.name = "Burger";
    food1.price = 33;
    food1.number = 1;
    FoodL.Add(food1);

    food2.name = "Pizza";
    food2.price = 65;
    food2.number = 2;
    FoodL.Add(food2);

    food3.name = "Fritter";
    food3.price = 20;
    food3.number = 3;
    FoodL.Add(food3);

    return FoodL;
}
```

Part 2 of the code:

```
public struct FoodItem
{
    public string name;
    public double price;
    public int number;
}
```

Part 3 of the code:

```
    foreach (FoodItem food1 in FoodL())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Nr. {0} {1}  {2:c}", food1.number, food1.name, food1.price);
        if (FoodL().Contains(food1.number))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Jeg har nummer 1");
        }
    }
```

Also don't mind the language it is in danish.

Comment: Well, what is problem exactly?

Comment: I think `Contains` will not work.

Comment: But the lop is strange as well

Comment: The problem is I wanted to use .Contains to check for a number in a struct but I guess it doesn't work. Like the .Contains can't use struct, as it's required to be a List<Int>. @PavelAnikhouski

Comment: @Stefan Yeah I don't think. I just wanted to ask as I was certain that there might have been a way to do so. The loop is strange rn as I had to do some testing first, to see what I'd get by the solutions I found on google.

Comment: As a side note, you are recreating the list on each loop by calling the method `FoodL()`. This is so wasteful. Store the list in a variable instead.

Comment: You take an item food1 out of the list, and you test if food1.number is in the list ?
It cannot be in the list, cause you didn't put it in the list, and it cannot even compile, cause contains is not accepting to search for an integer, cause it knows it's not a list of integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `Any` instead of `Contains`: if `FoodL()` has `Any` item such that `item.number` equals to `food1.number`

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 if (FoodL().Any(item => item.number == food1.number)) {
   ...
 }
```

Or you can *filter* the items with a help of `Where`: all items from `FoodL()` such that `item.number` equals to some value (let it be `numberToFind`)

```
var result = FoodL()
  .Where(item => item.number == numberToFind);

foreach (FoodItem found in result)
  Console.WriteLine($"{found.number} {found.name} {found.price:c} har nummer {numberToFind}");
```

Comment: And note that `FoodL` regenerates the list each time.

Comment: I will give it a try to see if it's useful.

Comment: Hmm the .Any didn't work. Though the .Contains(food1) worked just fine.

Comment: I take that back, it worked fine has .Contains(food1).

Comment: @luk19987 If `Contains` works fine, why you didn't approve my answer?:)

Comment: I just did:) @PavelAnikhouski

Comment: @luk19987 This answer is still approved, not the mine above:)

Comment: Sorry I mean't .Contains works fine and .Any also did.

Answer (score 4):

`Contains` method doesn't work in such way, you'll need to pass an instance of type `T` (`FoodItem` in your case)

```
if (FoodL().Contains(food1))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Jeg har nummer 1");
}
```

But this check doesn't make sense. You are getting the list and iterating over it, all items already in a list, you condition is always `true`.

Maybe you'll need to pass the number outside the loop and than find it in a list, using `Any` method for example, like

```cs
if (Food().Any(f => f.number == numberToFind))
{
}
```

`food1` in your snippet is loop variable, do not use it in comparison, the result will always be `true`

Comment: Alright, I didn't know that I that I don't use .Contains and lists that often. I will give it a try for sure and see what I get.

Comment: The first part of your post works fine. I will give the last part a try as well to see if there is a difference.

Answer (score 2):

you should use

```cs
FoodL().Contains(food1)
```

not

```cs
FoodL().Contains(food1.number)
```

Comment: Aight. Will give it a try.